# How to find whether a wordpress theme has a particular hook or not?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a Wordpress plugin and as per the plugin functionality requirement I need to find out if a Wordpress theme has a particular hook or not and in case if it doesn't have then I need to perform some action. Say for eg. show an alert message.

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress function **has_action** is used for this purpose.

Here's a really basic example showing how you can echo a message if the theme doesn't have the hook you need:

```
if(has_action('example_hook')) {
    do_action('example_hook');
} else {
        echo 'an example alert message';
}
```

[There's some more about has_action in the Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_action)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. 

I already had a check with has_action. has_action returns true even if some other plugin has attached function to that hook even if the hook is not present in the theme.

Comment: Good point, sorry about that. Sorry, it's very early here :) There is  current_theme_supports, but I'm not sure if that would work for any function. Edit: No, it's used for checking if the theme supports menus and stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. But current_theme_supports won't help. :-(